# Jquery: Is there an element based method similar to $(document).ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a method, similar to `$(document).ready()`, that can be applied
to an arbitrary element?  For example, if an ajax call sets the content
of a `DIV` and includes a lot of `IMG` tags, is there a way to trigger
a function call when all of the images have completed loading? Something
along the lines of:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/get/my/page.php',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response)
    {
       $('#my_element').html(response);
       $('#my_element').ready(function() {alert('all images loaded');});
        }      
    });
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: There are things that give it a decent try, like http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/ (if you're interested in images).

Comment: you might want to refer to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571890/check-if-a-given-dom-element-is-ready

Comment: You could create a script tag and add it after the div element.

Comment: Document ready would not get image loading either.

Comment: Could you not use the .length() method (jQuery) and wrap whatever you want to do in an if statement ,so if element.length for example?

Comment: I ended up going with something similar to Zaptree's solution.  Basically, I got the number of img tags in the content, and implementing a load() method on each img instance that incremented a counter.  When the counter value equals the number of img tags, I'm done.

Comment: Also, I wanted to thank all the responders.  You all make this a great community.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically interested in images being loaded, then you can try [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/), which seems to cover the example case that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Identical to $("document").ready() -- no, however, there are ways that you can make it work:

1. Put whatever function you need executed as a `callback` to the AJAX call:

   `$.get("link.php?item=1", function() {
          //callback function here
     })`
2. You can have an onchange event listener that triggers whenever the div is being changed and you can specifically trigger a function after a certain number of elements is loaded:

   `$("#div").on('change', function() {
          if ( $("#div").length > DESIRED_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS + 1)
          {
                  //Execute function here
          }
    })`

The on('change') can be used in any which way you want: it can trigger a function based on the number of elements, based on the nature of elements inside (if it's an image, a link, another div, etc), anything you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should do what you want.

```
onImagesLoaded('#my_element img',function(){
  console.log('images have all loaded')
});
function onImagesLoaded(seletor,callback){
    var $images = $(seletor);
    var count = $images.length;
    $images.each(function(img){
        //create an image
        var tempImage = new Image();
        //set a function for the onload event
        tempImage.onload = function(){
            count--;
            //if the count is 0 it means all images are done loading
            if(count===0){
                callback();
            }
        };
        //set the source to the src of the image.
        tempImage.src = $(img).attr('src');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var request = $.ajax({url: "/get/my/page.php", dataType: "html"});

request.done(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    // parse returned `data` string for html
    var html = $.parseHTML(data),
        // 
        len = html.length,
        div = $("div");
    // do stuff when all images loaded into `div`
    div.on("imgsready", function(e, htmlimgs, divimgs) {
        console.log("ready", htmlimgs, divimgs);
        $(e.target).prepend(divimgs + " images ready<br>" )
    });
    // set `div` html contents to `html` string 
    $.when(div.html(html)
           // return image `on` `load` event
           , $("img", div)
           .load(function(e) {
               // return image `promise` object
               return $(e.target).promise()
           })
    )
    .then(function (el, i) {     
        // if `div` contains `len` length images , call `imgsready` event
        return el.children(i).length === (i.length && len) 
               && el.children(i).eq(len -1).is("*") 
                  ? el.trigger("imgsready", [len, i.length])  
                  // else check again in 1000ms 
                  : setTimeout(function() {
                      el.children(i).eq(len -1).is("*") ?
                      el.trigger("imgsready", [len, i.length])
                      : console.log(el.children(i).length)
                    },1000)
    });       
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/vhuaen71/