# Determinate finish loading website in webView with Swift in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, webview, loading

i'm trying to create a webapp with swift in xcode, this is my current code:

```
IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    var theBool: Bool = false
    var myTimer = NSTimer()
    @IBOutlet var progressBar: UIProgressView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   let url = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")
   let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
   webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

I've a question, How i can determinate the finish loading of the page in webView?

Do you know a documentation that contains all the definitions of the WebView? I mean .. (start / end load, the current url, title page, etc ..)?

(Sorry for my English).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Through the `UIWebView` delegate call.

You need to set your webViews `delegate` to the current controller, and conform to the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol. When the webView finished loading the page `func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)` will get called.

Comment: the 'UIWebViewDelegate' protocol is now deprecated. So KVO in another way.

Answer (score 3):

For WKWebview there is also [wknavigationdelegate didfinish](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview), but not do the trick as the SO question **[WKWebView didn't finish loading, when didFinishNavigation is called - Bug in WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291534/wkwebview-didnt-finish-loading-when-didfinishnavigation-is-called-bug-in-wkw)** and this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30292043/6521116)** show.

I also found when the page to load is very complicate and dinamic, UIWebview's `webViewDidFinishLoad(- webView: UIWebView)` also not works.

And I think use native swift or objective-c to detect when the page is loaded is a bad choice. The more flexable and effective way is to use javascript to call the native swift code when page finishing loading. What's more this also work for a specific dom finishing loading event and very dynamic content.

For how to call swift from javascript refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25827368/6521116).

Here is a sample code for dynamic content with anjularjs.

js,

```
var homeApp = angular.module('home', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']);
homeApp
    .directive("printerinfo",
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            link: function() {       //call navite swift when page finishing loading
                try {
                    window.webkit.messageHandlers.testHandler.postMessage("Hello from JavaScript");
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log('The native context does not exist yet');
                }
            },

            templateUrl: "/static/tpls/cloud/app/printerinfo.php",
        }
    })
```

swift3,

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print(message.name)
    if(message.name == "testHandler") {
        //webpage content loaded
        print(Date())
        print("javascript test call swift")
    }
```

Here I **[use angularjs to check element ready](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21715256/6521116)**, you can also refter **[how-to-call-a-function-after-a-div-is-ready](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071697/6521116)**  or **[check-if-a-given-dom-element-is-ready](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6571890/6521116)** or **[jquery-ready-equivalent-event-listener-on-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19355791/6521116)** for more.