# webview didFinish Navigation getting called before page load completes - swift

Tags: ios, swift

It might be a silly question but as I am a newbie to swift so please help me out.

I am working on an IOS app in which we have to load different websites in webview, but the Issue is didFinish Navigation is getting called before whole page loads.

I am trying to Load Twitter "https://mobile.twitter.com/login", whose HTML should contain **Login Form** , but I am getting HTML of very first page loaded which is of no use.

Actually Twitter is applying some js to show the view of Login Page, is there any solution, to wait for completing all requests in this page, and then get the final HTML.

didFinish Navigation doesn't seems to work or wait.

Thanks

Comment: refer to this post   http://stackoverflow.com/a/43672099/6521116