# evaluateJavaScript() can't get stable content when access content produced by angular?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, swift3, wkwebview

I've a p tag with id test in my webpage, when I put it as follows everything works well.

html,

```
<p id="test">hhhhhhhhhhhh</p>
<body ng-app="home" ng-controller="HomeController" style="min-height:700px;">
  <printerinfo></printerinfo>
</body>
```

swift3,

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    self.wk.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;") { (result, error) -> Void in
    ->
       if error != nil {
            print(error)
       }
        print(result)
    }
}
```

While I move the p tag to template printerinfo, I get

> UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1,
>   WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: null is not an object
>   (evaluating 'document.getElementById('test').innerHTML')

most of the cases, and the remain cases works well with result `Optional(hhhhhhhh)`

And here is the ios wkwebview page content viewed from **Safari technology Preview's develpe > iphone device name**'s window. And I can access the innerHTML from the console.
[image]

For now I guess that the evaluateJavaScript has executed before the anjular has finished feeding the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by webpage's dynamic content. I solved this by useing javascript to check when the page is loaded, then notify native swift code to do next process.

For detail check this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43672099/6521116)**.