# UIWebView FinishLoad/Detection issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

when using a `UIWebView` I want to detect the moment a web page finishes loading in an `iOS` app.
For that I tried to use the solution mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149097/determinate-finish-loading-website-in-webview-with-swift-in-xcode).

But the problem is that the *webViewDidFinishLoad()* function gets called (almost right after the call to *loadRequest()*) way before the page appears on the display making the solution useless.
Am I missing something? Or is there a better (or different) way?

P.S. I am using Xcode Version 8.3.2 and iOS Version 10.3.2

Comment: Looks your moment html page has an async way to load content, that's why the webViewDidFinishLoad() function is called very fast.

Comment: I am just loading an arbitrary web page in a UIWebView within an iOS app, and not aware of any so called moment.html page. Forgive me please the lack of knowledge. Where can I check this moment.html?

Comment: Open the url in a Web Browser, like Chrome, Safari.  And then right click the page, choose "Check page source code" , then you are able to check the html source code.

Comment: That does not answer my question. I want my iOS app to work whatever page the user is going to open, the app cannot be depending on the way the chosen page is written. I am concerned with writing the iOS app not with writing some web page.

Comment: Since you cannot control the content of web page, you cannot control the timing of calling webViewDidFinishLoad() very exactly. Maybe there is a JS task in web page needs 1 min to do the job, but web page is finished load in 1 second.

Comment: Well, you may be right, but in that case I do not really see why webViewDidFinishLoad() exists.

Comment: It's working well for normal situations, usually, it will be called properly after loading an ordinary web page which is without the JS like I said above.

Comment: OK. The link I was using as a test is this: http://en.m.wikipedia.org

Comment: I have tested this link. webViewDidFinishLoad() is called after finished loading exactly. The delay is obviously. Maybe where to send the request in your code is wrong.

Comment: OK, thanks; then I must be doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145105/discussion-between-michel-and-yun-chen).

Answer (score 0):

The every page of HTML content loaded webViewDidFinishLoad will called... So I put three types of validation. Use it which one is preferred for you.

```
var webViewPages = 0

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webViewPages += 1
}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
    webViewPages -= 1
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    if (webView.isLoading){
        return
    }

    if webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.readyState") != "complete"{
        return
    }

    webViewPages -= 1

    if webViewPages > 0{
        return
    }
    // Calculating webview height
    let height = Int(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.scrollHeight")!)

}
```

Comment: In my case webViewDidFinishLoad() is only called once (far too soon), so I don't have any choice of checking something inside like you seem to be doing in your code.

Comment: What can I share which is relevant except this:    
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print(#function + " Hi, we are done!")
    }

Comment: This won't actually tell you when the page has been rendered, as I remember, there is no reliable way to know this.